# mic boost for kazer kiyo?

Tags: alsa, camera, microphone, alsamixer

I'm setting a new webcam, a razer kiyo, and I'm having some trouble with the microphone. It works, but it's really quiet. The "mic boost" option in alsamixer would seem to be a good choice, but this device doesn't have that option in alsa.

Is the mic boost option a truly device dependent thing, or is there a way to enable it in alsa? Or, at the device level?

Or, is there another way to boost the audio signal from a device? I realize that this would also boost the noise, but up to a point that might be acceptable.